# Inclusion-exclusion formula example

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

Compute the probability that a hand of 13 cards contains ace and king of at least one suit.

I cannot understand why we use hear inclusion-exclusion formula. For the "at least" problems the common solution is $1 - P(A)$.

So the questions are:

1. Why do we use inclusion-exclusion formula in this case?
2. In general when should we use this formula

Thank you

Comment: Can you add an explanation of how you would go about applying the $1-P(A)$ solution? What is your $A$ and why did you decide that doesn't work? Often there are multiple correct ways to arrive at the same result. I'm not claiming that's the case here, just that it's worth seeing your approach.

Comment: I want to know why the answer is in form inclusion-exclusion form.
I don't know why i should use this formula. 
The formula 1 - P(A) is not important in my question

Comment: Generally on Math stackexchange it's a good idea to give your thinking about a problem. There is a number of reasons for that; One if you consider the problem fully you can either solve it or at least get further along, two it is much easier to explain things when we know what your level of understanding is, three it shows that you are not just trying to get someone to do your work for you and four it can guide the people answering to touch on the subjects you seem to be misunderstanding.

Comment: @DRF: That's a great summary; I copied it for future use :-)

Comment: @joriki Thank you.:) I should really add: five showing that you tried to do some work makes other people more willing to help.

Comment: Are you comfortable with Set notations? Do you know about Set theory?

Comment: Simply because computing the probability of the complement is not quite easy here. Things would have been different if it only concerned a king or only an ace. Then $1-P(A)$ would have been easy to find. I think that's why @DRF asked you to come up with your solution. Diving into it you would have found out that it is complicated.